# bash: nested substitution only assigns last value to variable

Tags: bash, command, substitution

```
for f in $(for i in $(find Balzac/ -iname "20??????.txt"); do echo $i; done); do cat $f|cut -c 10-21; done|sort|uniq|egrep -Re "[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9].mp3"
```

yields a sorted, uniq'ed list of all mp3's from .txt-based playlists we use.

```
a=$(for f in $(for i in $(find Balzac/ -iname "20??????.txt"); do echo $i; done); do cat $f|cut -c 10-21; done|sort|uniq|egrep -Re "[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9].mp3")
```

though only contains the last value of that list.

Any idea why and what I can do to have the **whole list** in my variable? I am lost in this...

In the end I need two variants of the above to compare/diff the outputs against each other and see what is different within the files contained in the two directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making this unnecessarily complex by overloading operators. You can un-nest that by about three levels and still keep the functionality.

```
a=$(find Balzac/ -iname "20??????.txt" -exec cat {} + | cut -c 10-21 | sort | uniq | egrep -Re "[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9].mp3")
```

In fact I'm guessing the next thing your going to do is iterate over those files. If so you could skip the variable assignment and make something readable like this:

```
find Balzac/ -iname "20??????.txt" -exec cat {} + |
    cut -c 10-21 |
    sort | uniq |
    egrep -Re "[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9].mp3" |
    while read file; do
        #Do something with $file
    done
```

Comment: Very, very nicely done! An answer not just helping me but improving my  bash!! Thank you!

Comment: Weeellll, actually your short version only outputs the last entry, same as my example. And the long version outputs everything just nicely if I `echo` within the `while`-loop, but i cannot assign everything to a variable as that variable will not "survive" the `while` loop... In the end I need two variants of the above to `comp`are/`diff` the output against each other.

Comment: Are you sure the combination of cut, sort, uniq and egrep are actually returning more than one item in the first place? What happens when you run that line manually outside of the variable assignment?

Comment: then I get a whole list, as it should be. That's what confuses me profoundly. The command outside of the assignment work, but assigning it only one item is in the list.

Comment: My tests behave quite differently. What version of what shell are you using?

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)` on ubuntu 10.10

Comment: @Christian Are you doing this from an interactive shell or a script? If a script, how does your hash-bang line read?

Comment: Both, actually. Neither seems to work. the hash-bang reads `#!/bin/bash`